# Linq Question - Why is an outer join used here?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following query from the AdventureWorks DB

```
from customer in Customer
where customer.CustomerID == 20042
select new { 
 customer.AccountNumber, 
 Order = from order in customer.SalesOrderHeader
   select new { order }
 }
```

The Customer table has a 1:M relationship to SalesOrderHeader. The resulting T-SQL does a left outer join on the SalesOrderHeader table. Can someone tell me why? And, what if I wanted an inner join instead. How would I change this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inner join, use this:

```
from customer in Customer
where customer.CustomerID == 20042
from order in customer.SalesOrderHeaders
select new { customer.AccountNumber, Order = order }
```

If you want to just want to filter out customers that have no SalesOrderHeaders, use this:

```
from customer in Customer
where customer.CustomerID == 20042
where customer.SalesOrderHeaders.Any()
select new {  
 customer.AccountNumber,  
 Order =
   from order in customer.SalesOrderHeaders
   select order
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's one-to-many, you still have to allow for it being one-to-none. That is, **the customer may have no orders.** If you don't do an outer join, you will get no records back at all if this particular customer has no orders.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my question(s). Why does L2S automatically choose to do a left outer join, and, how does my query change if I want an inner join instead (where no records might get returned)?